# Login error not working on Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I created a website here - http://sdl2.alphalogichq.com/index.php/customer/account/login/

When I enter any email, for ex. abc@xyz.com and password - pass123 (both of them are wrong), it should ideally give me error Invalid login or password.

But here it just loads from cache and doesn't show the error. I need to force reload (CTRL + F5), and then it shows the error.

How can I change the behavior so it works properly?

Comment: I want to know admin credentials. Than I can help you with this

Comment: @HasmukhBaldaniya - http://sdl2.alphalogichq.com/index.php/admin123, username: admin, password: password1

Comment: Hey @dang where is my reward bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found X-Cache, X-Cache-Hits and X-Cacheable in response header that shows you are using some kind of caching. This is caching is implemented in server not by magento. I think this is Varnish cache as i found **X-Varnish** response header.

Cache HIT occurs when page load normally and cache miss occurs when you reload when load with CTRL+F5.

[image]
[image]

To resolve this issue ask your web hosting provide to disable Varnish cache. And i suggest you to use magento's cache and you can use Lesti FPC which is better to optimize website.